# How to bundle a custom Directive with External HTML Template in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**See my project structure below**

```
project
-Lib
    -MyCustomDirective(which i will use across multiple application)
      -customDir.js
      -customDirTmpl.html
-app
   -js
      -myfirstcontroller.js
      -main.js
   -partials
      -myfirstview.html
   -index.html
```

So , i am planning to create a custom directive, which i want to use across multiple projects. The issue here is, I want keep the template for my directive in separate html file. When my directive is loaded, my app is trying to find the "customDirTmpl.html" respective to the current application not respective to my "MyCustomDirective" folder.

I want to keep the templateUrl of my directive same across all project, i dont want to change it respective to any particular project.

**Sample code of "customDir.js"**

```
var myDir = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //I want this to be constant accross which ever project i use this directive
        templateUrl: 'customDirTmpl.html',
        link: function(scope){
            //to do something
        }
    };
};

app.directive("MyCustomDir", [myDir]);
```

Comment: You can programatically add directive into templateCache, so it will be fetched by templateUrl. Or introduce distribution building process, where directive source is built into single JS file you can use in different projects.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to have a utility in your directive library project that handles these needs.

Writing up an example will be quite tedious, so [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/js/core/services/ui-grid-util.js) is an example from the `ng-grid` project that demonstrates this.
Take a look at the `getTemplate` function property.

And [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/js/core/directives/ui-grid-footer.js) is it's example usage from the same project.
Notice the use of `gridUtil` for fetching the template.